# Multiple outer product in R

Tags: r, arrays, matrix

Suppose that we have four vectors and each vector is three-dimensional:

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
v2 <- c(4, 5, 6)
v3 <- c(2, 2, 2)
v4 <- c(3, 2, 1)
```

My goal is to create an array containing the outer product of each vector:

```
tmp_array <- array(NA, dim = c(3, 3, 4))
tmp_array[, , 1] <- outer(v1, v1)
tmp_array[, , 2] <- outer(v2, v2)
tmp_array[, , 3] <- outer(v3, v3)
tmp_array[, , 4] <- outer(v4, v4)
```

What we have now is a matrix containing the four vectors:

```
tmp_matrix <- rbind(v1, v2, v3, v4)
```

and I want to generate `tmp_array` by compactly using `tmp_matrix`.

I tried `outer(t(tmp_matrix), tmp_matrix)`, `outer(tmp_matrix, tmp_matrix)`, and so on, but these are not the solution.

How can I create `tmp_array` compactly? (i.e. without using loop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `apply(..., simplify = FALSE)` and `simplify2array()` to convert the list of outer product matrices to a 3-dimensional array.

```r
simplify2array(apply(tmp_matrix, 1, \(v) outer(v, v), simplify = FALSE))
```

```
, , v1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9

, , v2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   16   20   24
[2,]   20   25   30
[3,]   24   30   36

, , v3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    4    4
[2,]    4    4    4
[3,]    4    4    4

, , v4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    9    6    3
[2,]    6    4    2
[3,]    3    2    1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is very intuitive and compact!

Comment: Should point out that, per the documentation,  `simplify2array` is called **by**  `sapply` when the arg `simplify == TRUE` , but is not called by `apply`

Comment: Also, for clarity to newer `R` users,  notice that the use of  `\(v)` here is equivalent to `function(v)`

Answer (score 4):

Using `mapply()` you can `simplify2array()` by passing the `"array"` argument to the `simplify` parameter, you can achieve this like so:

```
mapply(
  function(row){
    outer(row, row, FUN = `*`)
  },
  split(
    tmp_matrix, 
    seq_len(nrow(tmp_matrix))
  ),
  SIMPLIFY = "array"
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tcrossprod` (instead of `outer`) + `dim<-`

```
> `dim<-`(do.call(cbind, lapply(list(v1, v2, v3, v4), tcrossprod)), c(3, 3, 4))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   16   20   24
[2,]   20   25   30
[3,]   24   30   36

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    4    4
[2,]    4    4    4
[3,]    4    4    4

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    9    6    3
[2,]    6    4    2
[3,]    3    2    1
```

---

## Generalization

To generalize the cases (not just `v1`, `v2`, `v3` and `v4`), we can build a custom function `f` like below

```
f <- function(...) {
    lst <- list(...)
    if (var(lengths(lst)) > 0) stop("Input vectors should be of the same length!")
    n <- length(lst[[1]])
    `dim<-`(do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, tcrossprod)), c(n, n, length(lst)))
}
```

such that

```
> f(v1, v2)
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   16   20   24
[2,]   20   25   30
[3,]   24   30   36


> f(1:5, 6:10, 11:15)
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   36   42   48   54   60
[2,]   42   49   56   63   70
[3,]   48   56   64   72   80
[4,]   54   63   72   81   90
[5,]   60   70   80   90  100

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  121  132  143  154  165
[2,]  132  144  156  168  180
[3,]  143  156  169  182  195
[4,]  154  168  182  196  210
[5,]  165  180  195  210  225


> f(v1, 1:2)
Error in f(v1, 1:2) : Input vectors should be of the same length!
```